# Hosting Website On Dropbox

Tags: html, dropbox, cname

hey people,
I have a simple 1 page site I have in my public dropbox folder, I can access it from the public url for that file.  What I want to do is have my site website.com redirect to the dropbox url but with the url in the browser still saying mysite.com.
As I said this is only a simple html page so it doesn't need to redirect to a different domain, just this one file.  Is this possible to do?  I read it might be possible using cname records but I'm not sure if it is how to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: This may help you: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=7897&replies=17

Comment: thanks but again that requires paid for hosting which defeats the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider might provide you with a way to redirect in a frame, thus preserving your domain in the browser address bar (I know 123-reg does this).

Comment: I'm trying to do it without paying for hosting though, thats why I'm looking at a way to do it with dns records

Comment: But do you already own a domain? You're not gonna really get far until you shell out some cash for one. You don't need hosting to do this, only lease a domain.